# Collect all transactions for each day and report total spent that day

Tags: python, date, sum

I have a DataFrame that looks like this

```
date    Burned
8/11/2019 7:00  0.0
8/11/2019 7:00  10101.0
8/11/2019 8:16  5.2
```

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
# Read data from file 'filename.csv' 
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
df = pd.read_csv("../example.csv") 
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 



df = df.assign(Burned = df['Quantity'])
df.loc[df['To'] != '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'Burned'] = 0.0
# OR:

df['cum_sum'] = df['Burned'].cumsum()
df['percent_burned'] = df['cum_sum']/df['Quantity'].max()*100.0

a=pd.concat([df['DateTime'], df['Burned']], axis=1, keys=['date', 'Burned'])

b=a.groupby(df.index.date).count()
```

But I get this error: `AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'date'`

Basically I am wanting to sort all these times just by day since it has timestamps throughout the day. I don't care what time of the day different things occured, I just want to get the total number of 'Burned' per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `parse_dates=['DateTime']` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for convert column `Datetime`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("../example.csv", parse_dates=['DateTime'])
```

Or first column:

```
df = pd.read_csv("../example.csv", parse_dates=[0])
```

In your solution is `date` column, so need [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with `sum`:

```
b = a.groupby(a['date'].dt.date)['Burned'].sum().reset_index(name='Total')
```

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Why does it say its not a datetime? Is there a way a way to make it datetime?

Comment: @Jackson - Use `df = pd.read_csv("../example.csv", parse_dates=['DateTime'])`

Comment: This gives me the total number of transaction on that day. How do I get the total number in the Burned column corresponding to these transactions?

Comment: @Jackson - then use `a.groupby(a['date'].dt.date)['Burned'].sum().reset_index(name='total')`

Comment: i get invalid syntax

Comment: using this: burned_per day = a.groupby(a['date'].dt.date)['Burned'].sum().reset_index(name='total')

Comment: @Jackson - tested and working nice, also if necessary try working with `df` like `df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['Burned'].sum().reset_index(name='Total')` or  `b = df.assign(date = df['date'].dt.date).groupby('date')['Burned'].sum().reset_index(name='Total')`

Comment: Could I ask you one more question? Originally the code you provided calculated the number of transactions. Can you put this here, but only include transactions in which the 'Burned' is not zero?

Comment: So really, the code that goes: a=pd.concat([df['DateTime'], df['Burned']], axis=1, keys=['date', 'Burned'])

How can I only include those that have a number in the 'Burned' Column, and just remove all those that are 0?

Comment: @Jackson - I think problem is values are not numeric, so try `df['Burned'] = df['Burned'].astype(float)` after remove `0`